Board game like monopoly where upon extracting cards you had to go and write computer code (even with speed or competition rewards)
I was wondering whether there exists any board game like monopoly where upon extracting cards you had to go and write computer code (even with speed or competition rewards).
This would be incentivating for both adults and children.
Because some children may like the board aspect, and, enjoy the break to go and code.
It is something that would allow for the soial aspects and the brain aspects, to, engage, mix and mingle, and interleave.
Would, this, though, be healthy?
Has, anyone, got any idea about whether this would be possible, or whether people with disabilities would feel some discomfort or not be able to grapple this.
Thank you for your suggestions.
Thank you for your feedback.
Thank you for your ideas.
Thank you for your implementations.
Please let me know if anything can be suggested, starting from this idea.
Thanks.
